# Android HCE card emulation not calling processCommandApdu

Tags: java, android, nfc, ndef, hce

I am trying to emulate an NDEF NFC tag but `processCommandApdu` is not being called. The service appears to start, I have tried a number of AID and nothing seems to work. I have also tried using PackageManager to start the HCE. Not sure what I am doing wrong?

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <service android:name=".MyHostApduService"
        android:exported="true" android:permission="android.permission.BIND_NFC_SERVICE">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.nfc.cardemulation.action.HOST_APDU_SERVICE"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data android:name="android.nfc.cardemulation.host_apdu_service" android:resource="@xml/apduservice" />
    </service>

    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>
</application>


<host-apdu-service xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:description="@string/servicedesc"
android:apduServiceBanner ="@string/servicedesc"
android:requireDeviceUnlock="false">
<aid-group android:description="@string/servicedesc"
    android:category="other">
    <aid-filter android:name="D2760000850101"/>
    <aid-filter android:name="A0A1A2" />
    <aid-filter android:name="B0B1B2B3" />
    <aid-filter android:name="C0C1C2C3C4" />
    <aid-filter android:name="D0D1D2D3D4D5" />
    <aid-filter android:name="E0E1E2E3E4E5E6" />
</aid-group>
```

```
public class MyHostApduService extends HostApduService {

enum CardSelect {
    SELECT_NONE,
    SELECT_NDEFAPP,
    SELECT_CCFILE,
    SELECT_NDEFFILE,
}

final static int APDU_CLA = 0;
final static int APDU_INS = 1;
final static int APDU_P1 = 2;
final static int APDU_P2 = 3;
final static int APDU_SELECT_LC = 4;
final static int APDU_SELECT_DATA = 5;
final static int APDU_READ_LE = 4;

final static int FILEID_CC = 0xe103;
final static int FILEID_NDEF = 0xe104;

final static byte INS_SELECT = (byte)0xa4;
final static byte INS_READ = (byte)0xb0;

final static byte P1_SELECT_BY_NAME = (byte)0x04;
final static byte P1_SELECT_BY_ID = (byte)0x00;

final static int DATA_OFFSET = 5;
final static byte[] DATA_SELECT_NDEF = { (byte)0xd2, (byte)0x76, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x85, (byte)0x01, (byte)0x01 };

final static byte[] RET_COMPLETE = { (byte)0x90, (byte)0x00 };
final static byte[] RET_NONDEF = { (byte)0x6a, (byte)0x82 };

final static byte[] FILE_CC = {
        (byte)0x00, (byte)0x0f,     //LEN
        (byte)0x20,                 //Mapping Version
        (byte)0x00, (byte)0x40,     //MLe
        (byte)0x00, (byte)0x40,     //MLc

        (byte)0x04,                 //Tag
        (byte)0x06,                 //LEN
        (byte)0xe1, (byte)0x04,     //signature
        (byte)0x00, (byte)0x32,     //max ndef size
        (byte)0x00,                 //read access permission
        (byte)0x00,                 //write access permission
};


private final static String TAG = "HostSampleService";

private CardSelect mCardSelect = CardSelect.SELECT_NONE;
private boolean mSelectNdef = false;
private byte[] mNdefFile = null;

public MyHostApduService() {
    super();
    System.out.println("+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++");
    //create ndef file
    NdefMessage ndef = createUriMessage(3, "hiro99ma.blogspot.com/");

    byte[] ndefarray = ndef.toByteArray();
    mNdefFile = new byte[2 + ndefarray.length];

    //NLEN
    mNdefFile[0] = (byte)((ndefarray.length & 0xff00) >> 8);
    mNdefFile[1] = (byte)(ndefarray.length  & 0x00ff);
    //NDEF message
    System.arraycopy(ndefarray, 0, mNdefFile, 2, ndefarray.length);
}

@Override
public void onDeactivated(int reason) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onDeactivated");
    mCardSelect = CardSelect.SELECT_NONE;
    mSelectNdef = false;
}

@Override
public byte[] processCommandApdu(byte[] commandApdu, Bundle extras) {
    boolean ret = false;
    byte[] retData = null;
    System.out.println("+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++");

    switch (commandApdu[APDU_INS]) {
        case INS_SELECT:

            switch (commandApdu[APDU_P1]) {
                case P1_SELECT_BY_NAME:
                    Log.d(TAG, "select : name");
                    // 1. NDEF Tag Application Select
                    if (memCmp(commandApdu, DATA_OFFSET, DATA_SELECT_NDEF, 0, commandApdu[APDU_SELECT_LC])) {
                        //select NDEF application
                        Log.d(TAG, "select NDEF application");
                        mSelectNdef = true;
                        ret = true;
                    } else {
                        Log.e(TAG, "select: fail");
                    }
                    break;

                case P1_SELECT_BY_ID:
                    Log.d(TAG, "select : id");
                    if (mSelectNdef) {
                        int file_id = 0;
                        for (int loop = 0; loop < commandApdu[APDU_SELECT_LC]; loop++) {
                            file_id <<= 8;
                            file_id |= commandApdu[DATA_OFFSET + loop] & 0xff;
                        }
                        switch (file_id) {
                            case FILEID_CC:
                                Log.d(TAG, "select CC file");
                                mCardSelect = CardSelect.SELECT_CCFILE;
                                ret = true;
                                break;

                            case FILEID_NDEF:
                                Log.d(TAG, "select NDEF file");
                                mCardSelect = CardSelect.SELECT_NDEFFILE;
                                ret = true;
                                break;

                            default:
                                Log.e(TAG, "select: unknown file id : " + file_id);
                                break;
                        }
                    } else {
                        Log.e(TAG, "select: not select NDEF app");
                    }
                    break;

                default:
                    Log.e(TAG, "select: unknown p1 : " + commandApdu[APDU_P1]);
                    break;
            }
            break;

        case INS_READ:
            Log.d(TAG, "read");
            if (mSelectNdef) {
                int offset = ((commandApdu[APDU_P1]) << 8) | commandApdu[APDU_P2];
                byte[] src = null;
                switch (mCardSelect) {
                    case SELECT_CCFILE:
                        Log.d(TAG, "read cc file");
                        src = FILE_CC;
                        ret = true;
                        break;

                    case SELECT_NDEFFILE:
                        Log.d(TAG, "read ndef file");
                        src = mNdefFile;
                        ret = true;
                        break;

                    default:
                        Log.e(TAG, "read: fail : no select");
                        break;
                }

                if (ret) {
                    retData = new byte[commandApdu[APDU_READ_LE] + RET_COMPLETE.length];
                    //read data
                    System.arraycopy(src, offset, retData, 0, commandApdu[APDU_READ_LE]);
                    //complete
                    System.arraycopy(RET_COMPLETE, 0, retData, commandApdu[APDU_READ_LE], RET_COMPLETE.length);
                }
                break;
            } else {
                Log.e(TAG, "read: not select NDEF app");
            }
            break;

        default:
            Log.e(TAG, "unknown INS : " + commandApdu[APDU_INS]);
            break;
    }

    if (ret) {
        if (retData == null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "return complete");
            retData = RET_COMPLETE;
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "------------------------------");
            for (byte ch : retData) {
                Log.d(TAG, Integer.toHexString(ch));
            }
            Log.d(TAG, "------------------------------");
        }
    } else {
        Log.e(TAG, "return no ndef");
        retData = RET_NONDEF;
    }
    return retData;
}


private boolean memCmp(final byte[] p1, int offset1, final byte[] p2, int offset2, int cmpLen) {
    final int len = p1.length;
    if ((len < offset1 + cmpLen) || (p2.length < offset2 + cmpLen)) {
        Log.d(TAG, "memCmp fail : " + offset1 + " : " + offset2 + " (" + cmpLen + ")");
        Log.d(TAG, "memCmp fail : " + len + " : " + p2.length);
        return false;
    }

    boolean ret = true;
    for (int loop = 0; loop < cmpLen; loop++) {
        if (p1[offset1 + loop] != p2[offset2 + loop]) {
            Log.d(TAG, "unmatch");
            ret = false;
            break;
        }
    }

    return ret;
}

private NdefMessage createUriMessage(int index, String uriBody) {
    try {
        byte[] uriBodyBytes = uriBody.getBytes("UTF-8");
        byte[] payload = new byte[1 + uriBody.length()];
        payload[0] = (byte)index;
        System.arraycopy(uriBodyBytes, 0, payload, 1, uriBodyBytes.length);
        return new NdefMessage(new NdefRecord[] {
                new NdefRecord(NdefRecord.TNF_WELL_KNOWN, NdefRecord.RTD_URI, new byte[0], payload)
        });
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
}





public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private NfcAdapter nfcAdapter;
private byte[] mNdefRecordFile;
Intent mIntent;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mIntent = new Intent(this, co.oneband.nfcem.MyHostApduService.class);
    this.startService(mIntent);


}
```

Comment: How do you try to read the tag?

Comment: on Pixel 2 NXP read tag app, iPhone xs NCF reader, Arduino RC522. The iPhone app responds with invalidated session, the Pixel nothing and the Arduino registers the tag with a UID (08 53 96 66) that changes every time I tap it.

Comment: <aid-filter android:name="D2760000850101"/>

Comment: My only thought is the intent filter is wrong?

Comment: <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.nfc.cardemulation.action.HOST_APDU_SERVICE"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            </intent-filter>

Comment: Fixed it, seems to be a hardware issue, tried it on another phone and works perfectly.